# AutoKey inserts blank lines

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, autokey

### Situation

- GNOME Shell
- [AutoKey / autokey-gtk](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/autokey)
- it has a predefined shortcut "adr" which should write an address after hitting space
- and a shortcut "date" which should write the current date (after hitting tab)

[image: Screenshot of settings in AutoKey]

### Problem

- no matter what I define, "adr" or "date" it always inserts as much blank lines as the template uses

Example:

- "date" should autocomplete after pressing space to "13/08/01" but it inserts one empty line
- "adr" should do my full address but it inserts 4 empty lines

### Question

What could be wrong with my AutoKey?
Do you need additional information?

Comment: were you able to solve it in the end? I am also in a similar situation.

Comment: No sorry. Since then I just deleted the snippets, created new, restarted and so on. At some point the error disappears but I can not tell why.

Answer (score 11):

Solution for me (running Xubuntu 14.04) was to provide a .service file in`/usr/share/dbus-1/services`.

- First I deleted all the example files and scripts, and created a new file. (This was on a fresh install of AutoKey.)
- Then I created an empty file `org.autokey.Service` under `/usr/share/dbus-1/services`
- In the `org.autokey.Service` file I put the following text:

  ```
  [D-BUS Service] 
  Name=org.autokey.Service 
  Exec=/usr/bin/autokey</code>
  ```
- Then I killed AutoKey via the taskmanager (AK already hang), and restarted AutoKey
- Tested it, and it works. No more blank lines. Text gets replaced like it should.

(I did not test the script functionality of AutoKey)

Comment: This is a very helpful tip. But I have one more problem. My AutoKey ignores diacritics.

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 18.04 for me

Answer (score 1):

Since I came across this when googling: I had the original problem with Ubuntu 18.04 too, but thankfully the original answer still worked for me 5 years later.

Create a new .Service file by typing `touch /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.autokey.Service` and open it in an editor such as nano by typing `sudo nano /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.autokey.Service`. Copy the lines provided by Dex:

```
[D-BUS Service] 
Name=org.autokey.Service 
Exec=/usr/bin/autokey
```

Restart Autokey and you're done.